# Deducting consecutive pandas columns after transposing and stacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```py
FORECAST_DATE                             Y0             Y1             Y2             Y3
              BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                            
BALANCE_DRAWN 1                  7744692.050    6195753.640    6195753.640    6195753.640
              2               2941409070.940 2016387035.960 2016387035.960 2016387035.960
              3                426236553.350  294727915.360  294727915.360  294727915.360
              4                 97310100.530   66594434.600   66594434.600   66594434.600
              6                  3789332.090    2317117.520    2317117.520    2317117.520
```

Produced by:

```py
result.T.stack()
```

I want to do the following deductions:
Y0 - Y-1 (will be NaN)

Y1 column values = Y1 - Y0

Y2 column values = Y2 - Y1

Y3 column values = Y3 - Y2

With result.diff(axis=1) I get:

```py
FORECAST_DATE                  Y0             Y1    Y2    Y3
              BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                               
BALANCE_DRAWN 1               nan   -1548938.410 0.000 0.000
              2               nan -925022034.980 0.000 0.000
              3               nan -131508637.990 0.000 0.000
              4               nan  -30715665.930 0.000 0.000
              6               nan   -1472214.570 0.000 0.000
```

Y1 - Y0 works and is put into the Y1 column, but for the other columns it does not work.

Any suggestions on how to do this ?

Comment: You did not add the code you're using to write the values, but my guess is that you're updating the same columns you're using to do the next calculations, based on the names you used. Maybe try to store the answer in different named columns, or make a copy of your dataframe.

Comment: sorry, i cannot understand your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```py
#substracting the columns besides the first one because it errors that there is no column Y-1
for i in range(1, len(formatted.columns)):
    formatted["Y" + str(i)] = formatted["Y" + str(i)] - formatted["Y" + str(i-1)]

#set Y0 to NaN
formatted["Y0"] = "NaN"

Result:

FORECAST_DATE                   Y0             Y1             Y2             Y3
              BOOK_SEGMENT_ID                                                  
BALANCE_DRAWN 1                NaN   -1548938.410    7744692.050   -1548938.410
              2                NaN -925022034.980 2941409070.940 -925022034.980
              3                NaN -131508637.990  426236553.350 -131508637.990
              4                NaN  -30715665.930   97310100.530  -30715665.930
              6                NaN   -1472214.570    3789332.090   -1472214.570
```

If anyone has a better looking solution than this. I will gladly accept it.